# Checking for Angular $http type on $resource error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

In Angular 1.6.x I may have several promise invocations, involving e.g. a dialog display, an HTTP call using `$resource`, and some processing:

```
showDialog()
  .then(foo => {
    return sendDataToServer(foo); //uses $resource
  })
  .then(bar => {
    processData(bar);
  })
  .catch(error) {
    //TODO handle problems here
  });
```

If the dialog is canceled (using Angular Material), `error` will be `undefined`. That I can handle.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for `$resource` says:

> On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object ….

So how can I tell if `error` is the HTTP response? Do I compare it to an injected singleton instance of `$http`? Is there a type I can use with `instanceof`?

Basically I want to do certain things if there was an HTTP error, but other things if there was a processing error. For example, I may want to log the HTTP data:

```
  .catch(error) {
    $log.error("FooBar Error", angular.toJson(error.data));
  });
```

Sure I could check to see if there is an `error.data` attribute, but that seems a bit indirect and still doesn't tell me if the error really is an HTTP response. (Maybe it was an exception with extra `data` that means something entirely different.)

Comment: Put the catch for each part that you expect to throw after the .then() in question.

    .then(function(){})
    .catch(function(){})
    .then(function(){})
    .catch(function(){})

Comment: Instead of checking for `error.data` why don't you check for more? check for error.data, error.status, error.headers - config etc. I mean if it quacks like a duck... it is probably an HTTP duck :P